# SLSQP vs Trust Region Constrained Algorithms

Tags: python, constraint-programming

I have gone through [scipy constrained algos](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/tutorial/optimize.html#sequential-least-squares-programming-slsqp-algorithm-method-slsqp) explanation, however, not much is mentioned about the differences, pros and cons of the 'trust-const' and 'slsqp' methods. I particularly wanted to know their suitability based on the following aspects:

1. Number of optimization parameters
2. Differentiability of constraints
3. Initialization of parameters (interior vs exterior regions)
4. Speed
5. Any other important metric

Comment: You'll never understand what those algorithms are from those descriptions - and likely no one else will either. Nor will you be able to discern the quality of the implementations. There is a little more info, including references, at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html . There you can see reference to the original (Fortran) SLSQP algorithm documentation at http://degenerateconic.com/uploads/2018/03/DFVLR_FB_88_28.pdf . That first link also provides algorithm references for trust-constr .

Comment: Thanks @MarkL.Stone for the extremely useful links. As I'm going through them I realize that scipy missed a lot on documentation about optimization. Off topic, loved your linkedin articles. Cocky, but really funny.

Answer (score 1):

as you mention the documentation is not very insightful when comes to comparing and choosing different algorithms, I think in [this paragraph](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#:%7E:text=and%20lower%20bounds.-,Constrained%20Minimization,-Method%20COBYLA%20uses) I found the major takeaways, not very deep as you might want, but was helpful for me at least

> Method COBYLA uses the Constrained Optimization BY Linear Approximation (COBYLA) method [9], [10], [11]. The algorithm is based on linear approximations to the objective function and each constraint. The method wraps a FORTRAN implementation of the algorithm. The constraints functions ‘fun’ may return either a single number or an array or list of numbers.

> Method SLSQP uses Sequential Least SQuares Programming to minimize a function of several variables with any combination of bounds, equality and inequality constraints. The method wraps the SLSQP Optimization subroutine originally implemented by Dieter Kraft [12]. Note that the wrapper handles infinite values in bounds by converting them into large floating values.

> Method trust-constr is a trust-region algorithm for constrained optimization. It swiches between two implementations depending on the problem definition. It is the most versatile constrained minimization algorithm implemented in SciPy and the most appropriate for large-scale problems. For equality constrained problems it is an implementation of Byrd-Omojokun Trust-Region SQP method described in [17] and in [5], p. 549. When inequality constraints are imposed as well, it swiches to the trust-region interior point method described in [16]. This interior point algorithm, in turn, solves inequality constraints by introducing slack variables and solving a sequence of equality-constrained barrier problems for progressively smaller values of the barrier parameter. The previously described equality constrained SQP method is used to solve the subproblems with increasing levels of accuracy as the iterate gets closer to a solution.